# No visible @interface

Tags: objective-c

The following code give me an error of "no visible @interface for BankAccount declares the selector getAccountNumber"
Why? Please help

```
// BankAccount.h  
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
@interface BankAccount: NSObject  
@property long accountNumber;  
@end  

// BankAccount.m  
#import "BankAccount.h"  
@implementation BankAccount  
@end

//main.m  
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
#import "BankAccount.h"  
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])  {  
    BankAccount *account1 = [[BankAccount alloc] init];  
    [account1 setAccountNumber: 34543212];  
    NSLog(@" Account No = %li",  [account1 getAccountNumber]);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The generated getter is `accountNumber`, not `getAccountNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `[account1 getAccountNumber]` to `[account1 accountNumber]` .

Comment: You don't need the `@synthesize` in recent versions of the tools

Comment: Synthesize or not that wouldn't change the problem, he is using it from the main.